# How to update field from one table to another based on a time range join?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, range

I have tried many different things but I am really struggling with this issue. I am used to MySQL, SQLite, and other databases but I can't seem to figure this one out in Access.

I have two tables that I want to join based on if the timestamps of table1 fall within a range of timestamps in table2 grouped by ID. See the following:

Table1:

```
ID  Timestamp
    8:00 AM
    8:01 AM
    8:02 AM
    8:03 AM
    8:04 AM
    8:05 AM
    8:06 AM
    8:07 AM
    8:08 AM
    8:09 AM
    8:10 AM
    8:11 AM
    8:12 AM
    8:13 AM
    8:14 AM
    8:15 AM
    8:16 AM
    8:17 AM
    8:18 AM
    8:19 AM
```

Table2:

```
ID  Timestamp
1   8:00 AM
1   8:02 AM
1   8:04 AM
1   8:06 AM
2   8:10 AM
2   8:12 AM
2   8:14 AM
2   8:16 AM
```

What I want to happen in Table1:

```
ID  Timestamp
1   8:00 AM
1   8:01 AM
1   8:02 AM
1   8:03 AM
1   8:04 AM
1   8:05 AM
1   8:06 AM
    8:07 AM
    8:08 AM
    8:09 AM
2   8:10 AM
2   8:11 AM
2   8:12 AM
2   8:13 AM
2   8:14 AM
2   8:15 AM
    8:16 AM
    8:17 AM
    8:18 AM
    8:19 AM
```

Here is what I tried initially (and wish would work) but have gone through many iterations of different queries without getting anywhere.

```
UPDATE Table1 
  SET Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
  WHERE Table1.Timestamp IN (SELECT Table2.Timestamp GROUP BY Table2.ID);
```

I either get no output (Table1.ID remains empty) or I get the error "Operation must use an updatable query".

Comment: Tags belong in the *Tags* section, not in the title.

Comment: Have you tried simply *JOINing* the tables instead of using the **WHERE ... IN ...** criteria?

Comment: Hi Pieter, it would not let me add "Access" as a tag as I do not have enough reputation hence why it was in the title. How can I join them as there is nothing to join them on? Later on I will be able to join them based on ID but for now I need to populate the ID column first based on if the timestamps are within the ranges of timestamps grouped by ID in the second table. Thanks!

Comment: But you are not doing any of the specified calculation in your subquery. No wonder your results are not as desired.

Comment: Hi Pieter, sorry I am still a beginner. What specified calculation do I need to do in the subquery? Any idea what in this query is causing the "Operation must use an updatable query"? Thanks!

Comment: Joining the tables will merely provide matches only on identical timestamps, which is not OP's intent. Why doesn't 8:16 have an ID?

Comment: because of a typo, sorry. Your answer worked miracles, thanks OverMind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a temp table and use it as a temporary recordset to use to search the records. The reason for this is that you need the Min/Max timestamp per ID, which requires an aggregate query, which cannot be used in an update query.

```
SELECT Table2.ID, 
Min(Table2.TS) AS MinOfTS, 
Max(Table2.TS) AS MaxOfTS
 INTO try      '<- this is your temporary table.
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.ID;
```

Now that we have values we can use to search with in our temp table, we can just reference that in our `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE Table1, try SET Table1.ID = [try].[ID]
WHERE (((Table1.TS) Between [try].[minofts] And [try].[maxofts]));
```

Edit: I suppose you could use a `DLookup` - but they tend to run extremely slow compared to this method.

Comment: Thanks OverMind! This is an excellent, concise, and explanatory answer. I guess I was hung up on Access not being able to use Group By. Your answer works perfectly! Hopefully some other poor soul like me will come across this one day and figure it out a lot quicker than I did. Thanks again!

Comment: @nellywilson No problem. Access SQL can be very foreign to some if they don't have experience with it. Glad this worked out for you.